# Vertical Space Between Environments

Tags: spacing, environments

im trying to get rid of the vertical space between environments, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{justify}
        Something
    \end{justify}
    \begin{justify}
        Something else
    \end{justify}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like it to be like

```
Something
Something else
```

Right next below

I've tried some methods but unsuccessfully

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A solution, if any, depends on the environment. What is it?

Comment: Do you need to use two environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the difference between `\centering` and `\begin{center}` the environment form is a display list that adds space, and you want the command form

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

{\justifying
        Something

}{\justifying
        Something else

}
\end{document}
```